# Removing outlet connections without disabling IBOutlet

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I added a second ViewController to my Swift app and I'm trying to add IBOutlets to it just as I did in my first ViewController. For some reason the file gets corrupted and whenever I click the button that leads to the second screen that connects with the new ViewController (called MyOwnViewController) the app gets an error that says "Unknown class MyOwnViewController in Interface Builder file," and "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key showOption3.'" showOption3 is the name of the IBOutlet I'm trying to call when the screen launches.

```
import Foundation

class MyOwnViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var showOption3: UILabel!

@IBOutlet var showOption4: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var voteCount1 = PFObject(className: "VoteCount")
    voteCount1["choices"] = 2
    voteCount1["votes"] = Int()
    voteCount1["votes2"] = Int()
    voteCount1["optionName"] = String()
    voteCount1["optionName2"] = String()
    voteCount1["objectId"] = String()
    voteCount1["pollNumber"] = Int()

    var query = PFQuery(className: "VoteCount")
    query.countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (count: Int32, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            let randNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(count)))
            query.whereKey("pollNumber", equalTo: randNumber)
            query.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock {
                (voteCount1: PFObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                if error != nil {
                    NSLog("%@", error)
                } else {
                    let votes = voteCount1["votes"] as Int
                    let votes2 = voteCount1["votes2"] as Int
                    let option1 = voteCount1["optionName"] as String
                    let option2 = voteCount1["optionName2"] as String
                    self.showOption3.text = "\(option1)"
                    self.showOption4.text = "\(option2)"
                }
            }
        } else {
            println("error \(error)")
        }
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

I have tried removing the connection for the IBOutlets in the Connections Inspector, which does remove the error and allows the second View Controller to appear, but it also disables the IBOutlets altogether. I still need the IBOutlets to show up when the MyOwnViewController screen appears.

Comment: you just need to remove the action associated with that button.

Comment: I still need the action to take place, so I can't remove it completely. That's the whole dilemma.

Comment: you don't need a link with the IBOutlet but only the IBAction. So it is really simple. Just right click on that button you will see a linkage b/w your button and the File Owner in IBOutlet section just remove it and all will work fine.

Comment: It's actually not a button, it's a label. I'm trying to make it display text via an IBOutlet. That's what's corrupting my ViewController for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the action, two ways :

1) You go in the storyboard and then you click on the button with the outlet and then on the right panel , you click on the round with an array and the on the cross with the connection.

2) You remove the line of code with the "@IBOutlet".

Hope this helps,

Comment: What if I still need that action to take place?

Comment: Then you can't remove the action ?! Your problem may be that you use IBOutlet instead of IBAction ?

Comment: I need to use IBOutlet. It's not a button, it's a text label that I'm trying to make display a word using this line of code: self.showOption3.text. In my first ViewController, it worked just fine but for my new ViewController it won't work for some reason. I'm basically using the same code that I used in my first ViewController.